# How would I calculate this excel formula in SQL? Pk/Cpk

Tags: mysql, sql, cp

Simple Query to show the columns

```
SELECT TL4_Cp_Cpk.Tread_Length_LSL AS LSL,
    TL4_Cp_Cpk.Tread_Length_USL AS USL,
    TL4_Cp_Cpk.Tread_Length AS Length,
FROM TL4_Cp_Cpk
```

Formula from excel

```
=MIN(USL-mu:mi-LSL)/(3*sigma)
```

- `MIN`  = minimum function,
- `USL` is a column,
- `LSL` is a column,
- `mu` = average of the length column,
- `sigma` = STDEV of the Length column.

I know how to get the STDEV (sigma) and average (mu) but not how to use them together to get an output for the formula.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? And what is `mu:mi` supposed to be?

Comment: MySQL. Sorry that is a typo I missed. it should be =MIN(USL-mu:mu-LSL)/(3*sigma)

Comment: So, what's `mu:mu` supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
With cte as (
Select (t1.Tread_Length_LSL - t2.mu)/(3 * sigma) as LSL, 
(t2.mu - t1.Tread_Length_USL)/(3 * sigma) as USL
From TL4_Cp_Cpk t1 Cross Join
     (Select Avg(Tread_Length) as mu, Stdev(Tread_Length) as sigma 
       From TL4_Cp_Cpk) t2
),

cte2 as (Select Case When USL < LSL  Then USL
            Else LSL
            End As Min_Value
From cte)

Select min (Min_Value) from cte2
```

Comment: That is very helpful. Solution to problems usually bring more questions though. If I wanted to do a group by for a Column called Run_ID where would I add that? Sorry for the extra questions but I'm trying to get better at SQL.

Comment: If Run_ID is a PK for every row? Will be helpful if you can give sample rows in your table and sample output.